# Euclidean Metric satisfying the Triangle Inequality - Is there missing details in the proof given here?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, inequality, metric-spaces

The image below comes from the book Geometry and Topology by Miles Reid and Balazs Szendroi. They prove the Triangle Inequality, which is stated below $(2)$. I am happy with the proof of the inequality. What I'm not satisfied about is the proof of equality in the *only if* direction, that is if we assume equality in $(2)$ then $\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{x}+\lambda(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})$ with $0\le\lambda\le 1$.

In the very last line in the image (the line where it ends with QED) it says that $\mathbf{u}=\mu \mathbf{v}$ with $\mu\ge 0$ and if we rewrite this in terms of $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z}$ we should get the desired conclusion. After making the substitution we obtain $\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{x} + \frac{\mu}{\mu+1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})$ and it looks good that $\lambda = \frac{\mu}{\mu+1}$ because it looks like $0\le\lambda\le 1$. But if we look closely $\frac{\mu}{\mu+1}<1$. What happened to the case where $\lambda =1$?

**Thoughts:**
My reasoning as to why we are missing the case $\lambda=1$ is because we missed the case where $\mathbf{u}\neq \mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$. In this case $\mathbf{u}\neq\mu\mathbf{v}$ for any $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$. So it doesn't necessarily follow that if $u_iv_j=u_jv_i$ for all $i,j$ and $\sum u_i v_i\ge 0$ then $\mathbf{u}=\mu\mathbf{v}$ with $\mu\ge 0$.

I agree that if we assume equality in $(2)$, this is equivalent to assuming equality in $(7)$ which is also equivalent to $u_iv_j=u_jv_i$ for all $i,j$. But to deduce $\mathbf{u}=\mu\mathbf{v}$ we are actually assuming that $\mathbf{v}\neq \mathbf{0}$ since $\displaystyle \mu=\frac{u_j}{v_j}$ for some $v_j\neq 0$ (One can see that if equality holds in $(7)$ then $\displaystyle u_i=\frac{u_j}{v_j}v_i$ for all $i$ where $\displaystyle\mu=\frac{u_j}{v_j}$ and $j$ is fixed).

**Remark:** Actually $\mu\ge 0$ is beside the point. The only reason why this holds is because we need $\sum u_i v_i\ge 0$ and since equality in $(7)$ implies $u_i v_j=u_j v_i$ for all $i,j$, it follows that if $\mathbf{v}\neq \mathbf{0}$ then for some $v_j\neq 0$ it follows that $\displaystyle u_i=\frac{u_j}{v_j}v_i$ for all $i$. So if $\displaystyle\frac{u_j}{v_j}=\mu<0$ then either $(u_j<0$ and $v_j>0)$ or $(u_j>0$ and $v_j<0)$. Hence it must be the case that there exists $u_k v_k>0$ such that $k\neq j$. But then $\displaystyle\frac{u_j}{v_j}<\frac{u_k}{v_k}$ which is a contradiction.

The point is equality in $(7)$ holds if and only if $(\mathbf{u}=\mu\mathbf{v}$ or $\mathbf{v}=\mu\mathbf{u})$. Hence we take into account the case $\mathbf{u}\neq\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$.

**Question:** Is this the correct reasoning as to why $\lambda=1$ isn't taken into account of in the proof? Or is there something deeper going on?

[image: Triangle Inequality]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right - it's an oversight. "$u$ and $v$ are proportional" is, of course, not (quite) the same thing as "$u = \mu v$ for some $\mu$".